# convert strings into variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, dry

I have declared variables inside a map object, each one represents a location. Then i am using a listener to run a function on a click event so it shows some HTML and remove the previous shown. Works fine but i can see that starts to get repetitive very soon, not a DRY approach.

The HTML to be shown goes as follows:

```
<div class="grow-details">
    <h2>Informacion del Growshop</h2>

    <div id="imperioSeedsRecoleta" class="hide">
        <h3>Imperio Seeds</h3>
        <h5>Calle Dardignac #527</h5>

        <p>Sector Patronato</p>
        <p>Recoleta</p> 
        <p>Metro: Estacion Patronato</p>
        <p>Contacto: 56 9 73507638 (Whatsapp)</p>
        <p>Lunes a Viernes: 10:00 a 19:00 (Horario Continuado)</p>
        <p>Sabados              : 10:00 a 16:00 hrs</p>
        <p>Encargado tienda: Vicente Ogaz</p>
    </div>

    <div id="somaGrowshop" class="hide">
        <h3>Soma Growshop</h3>

        <p>José Miguel de La Barra 454, Santiago de Chile</p>
        <p>Lun-Dom: 10:00-22:00</p>
        <p>Cafetería Sensorial</p>
        <p>No requiere reservas, Para llevar y Mesas en el exterior</p>
        <p>Sirve Café y Bebidas</p>
        <p>Teléfono (2) 2639 0442</p>
    </div>

    <div id="growGames" class="hide">
        <h3>Grow Games | Grow Shop Chile</h3>

        <p>GrowGames es un GrowShop, centrados en el trato directo con nuestros clientes, resolviendo cualquier duda que pueda surgirles, dando la solución mas económica y rápida posible.</p>
        <p>Local 65,Merced 832,Santiago,Región Metropolitana</p>
        <p>+56 9 8 158 00 45 | +56 2 2 696 82 97</p>
        <p>info@growgames.cl</p>
    </div>

    <div id="dinafem" class="hide">
        <h3>Dinafem Store Santiago</h3> 
        <p>Av. Libertador Bernardo Ohiggins #482 8330030 Santiago Chile | Ecuador #78 Viña del Mar Chile</p>
        <p>Llámanos ahora: Tienda Alameda: +569 64208716 Tienda en linea: +569 965061168</p>
        <p>Escríbanos un Email a: compras@dinafemstore.cl</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS files, variables represent a location in the map, and below are the listeners.

```
var dinafem = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.4420634, lng: -70.64286479999998},
    map: map,
    title: 'Dinafem'
});
var growGames = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.4384068, lng: -70.64886280000002},
    map: map,
    // icon: 'assets/logo.png',
    title: 'Grow Games'
});
var imperioSeedsRecoleta = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.4319006, lng: -70.64667589999999},
    map: map,
    // icon: 'assets/logo.png',
    title: 'Imperio Seeds'
});
var somaGrowShop = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.4371948, lng: -70.6435702},
    map: map,
    title: 'Soma Grow Shop',
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
```

My intention is to loop through each id name in the HTML to extract the id name convert it into a variable so i can call de adsListener method.

```
imperioSeedsRecoleta.addListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("imperioSeedsRecoleta").removeAttribute("class", "hide");

    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children.length; i++) {        
        document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children[i].setAttribute("class", "hide");       
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children[i].id == "imperioSeedsRecoleta") {
            document.getElementById("imperioSeedsRecoleta").removeAttribute("class", "hide");
        }
    }
});

somaGrowShop.addListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("somaGrowshop").removeAttribute("class", "hide");

    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children.length; i++) {        
        document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children[i].setAttribute("class", "hide");       
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children[i].id == "somaGrowshop") {
            document.getElementById("somaGrowshop").removeAttribute("class", "hide");
        }
    }
});

growGames.addListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("growGames").removeAttribute("class", "hide");

    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children.length; i++) {        
        document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children[i].setAttribute("class", "hide");       
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children[i].id == "growGames") {
            document.getElementById("growGames").removeAttribute("class", "hide");
        }
    }
});

dinafem.addListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("dinafem").removeAttribute("class", "hide");

    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children.length; i++) {        
        document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children[i].setAttribute("class", "hide");       
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children[i].id == "dinafem") {
            document.getElementById("dinafem").removeAttribute("class", "hide");
        }
    }
});
```

If i create an empty array i can loop through each div id and push each id name that i conveniently named the same as its location variable

```
var growsArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children.length; i++) { 
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children[i].id !== "") {       
        growsArray.push(document.getElementsByClassName("grow-details")[0].children[i].id);
    }
}
```

Each name is returned as a string so i cannot call .addlistener method to it. Is there any way to convert this strings to a variable?

Comment: Could you clarify the following? *My intention is to loop through each id name in the HTML to extract the id name convert it into a variable so i can call de adsListener method.*

Comment: not really man.. the problem with your suggestion is that calling window[id] would returnthe HTML that i want to display but not the location on the map. Is on the "pin" of the map where i want to call the click function..  mcgraphics answer was pretty close but i am using the addListener function that the Google maps API provides for the "pins" and it won´t let me do a for loop over my growsArray

Answer (score 0):

When you create your variables, put them into an object, then you can reference them by name.

For example

```
var dinafem = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.4420634, lng: -70.64286479999998},
    map: map,
    title: 'Dinafem'
});
```

Would become:

```
var variables = {};
variables.dinafem = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.4420634, lng: -70.64286479999998},
    map: map,
    title: 'Dinafem'
});

variables.growGames = //...
variables.imperioSeedsRecoleta = //...
```

Then you can reference them all by string name using:

```
variables['dinafem']; //this is the marker
```

So assuming your growsArray has the list of strings in it, you would loop over that list and use each value to get the marker out of the "variables" object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < growsArray.length; i++) {
    var stringName = growsArray[i];
    variables[stringName].addListener(...);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks mas, it almost solve it but i encounter when trying ro work variables['dinafem']; in a loop. I have all the strings in an array called growsArray = ["dinafem", "imperioSeedsRecoleta", "growGames"], if i call variables[growsArray[0]] it works fine but if i put this in a loop and call variables[growsArray[i]] it does not work...

Comment: If you are looping over an array of strings, just replace 'dinafrem' with you item in your array:  variables[growsArray[i]].addEventListener()

Comment: Putting the letter " i " on variables[growsArray[i]] makes it wrong if i do variables[growsArray[0]] works fine for the first item. I think it might have to do with the fact that this is being done inside a Google map initMap function.. that is why the method is addListener and not addEventListener.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but i tried that before and did not work also... same problem.. if i user a number instead of " i " works fine for that item

Answer (score 0):

Once you have populated your `growsArray` with the names, you can access your global variables via `window[...]`, and add event listeners like this:

```
for (var id of growsArray) {
    window[id].addEventListener('click', function() { ... } );
}
```

Comment: thanks, nice trick but the click event should be triggered on the location variable, not the HTML object.. as far as i can see the window[id] is giving me access to the HTML node

Comment: If you want to *trigger* the event, then why are you looking to use `addEventListener`? That does not trigger anything?

Comment: BTW, when `id == 'imperioSeedsRecoleta'` then `window[id]` will refer to whatever you put in `var imperioSeedsRecoleta`, which from the code you have shared is the location variable.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your variables into object keys, abstract your event handler a bit and iterate over the object keys (note that I've removed some problematic pieces of your code (`removeAttribute('class', 'hide')` should be `classList.remove('hide')` and reduced the number of DOM queries by storing elements in variables:

```
var locations = {
    'dinafem': new google.maps.Marker(...),
    'growGames': new google.maps.Marker(...),
    'imperioSeedsRecoleta': new google.maps.Marker(...),
    'somaGrowShop': new google.maps.Marker(...)
}

var clickHandler = function(selector) {
    return function (event) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(selector);
        var growDetails = document.querySelector("grow-details");

        elem.classList.remove("hide");

        for (i = 0; i < growDetails.children.length; i++) {        
            growDetails.children[i].classList.add("hide");       
            if (growDetails.children[i].id == selector) {
                elem.classList.remove("hide");
            }
        }
    }
}

Object.keys(locations).forEach(function(location) {
    locations[location].addListener('click', clickHandler(location));
});
```